# Can two electrons have the same momentum and spin directions?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, pauli-exclusion-principle

I am trying to understand the Pauli exclusion principle. Here is an except from Feynman Lectures on Physics

> It just isn’t possible at all for two Fermi particles—such as two electrons—to get into exactly the same state. You will never find two electrons in the same position with their two spins in the same direction. **It is not possible for two electrons to have the same momentum and the same spin directions.** If they are at the same location or with the same state of motion, the only possibility is that they must be spinning opposite to each other.

http://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/III_04.html [emphasis added]

I don't understand about "It is not possible for two electrons to have the same momentum and the same spin directions." Is it not possible for two electrons, even if they are at *different* locations, to have the same momentum and the same spin directions?

Comment: I must admit I don't fully understand this quote. If you know the two electrons are at a particular position then they could have any momentum. The Pauli exclusion principle forbids two electrons from occupying the same quantum state in a system, it doesn't refer to their position.

Comment: In words, a particle with a definite momentum is not located (or more precisely, *localized*) anywhere.  Put another way, the 'spread' in location is inversely proportional to the 'spread' in momentum.  Localizing momentum (position) necessarily means delocalizing position (momentum).

Comment: Have a look at this page http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/pauli.html

Comment: @annav Not really impressed with that description. It doesn't mention spin, says several times that no two fermions can exist in the same energy state (when often exactly two can!) and doesn't spell out why the initial postulated wavefunction is no good for indistinguishable particles (i.e. that $\psi^2$ only stays the same after swapping the particle identities if $\psi_1^{2}(a)=\psi_1^{2}(b)$ etc., which cannot be true in general).

Comment: @RobJeffries   Hmm, do you not know what fermions means? half integer spin?

Comment: @anna v I understand well enough, but are you defending "No two fermions can exist in identical energy quantum states" and "no two electrons in a solid can have identical energy states"? Or, following the link to Fermi-level, I see; "electrons are fermions and by the PEP cannot exist in identical energy states"? It seems the authors have forgotten that fermions have spin.

Comment: Yes, if you look at solutions for atoms, http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/qunoh.html , the energy states are uniquely defined by n, l, m quantum numbers. spin allows to have two electrons at the same m if they have opposite spins, not the same. the same for any other fermions. there would not be a periodic table otherwise, with no PEP they would all crowd at the lowest energy level

Answer (score 4):

> Is it not possible for two electrons, even if they are at different locations, to have the same momentum and the same spin directions?

A particle that is in a pure momentum state has a wavefunction that is a sinusoidal plane wave. Therefore its position is infinitely uncertain. You can also see this in the Heisenberg uncertainty relation, $\Delta p \Delta x \gtrsim h$; if $\Delta p=0$, then $\Delta x$ blows up to infinity.

I'm in Los Angeles, and let's assume that you're in Chicago. Obviously if I manipulate an electron here, it can have no effect on an electron that you're manipulating there. But I cannot prepare an electron in Los Angeles in a state of pure momentum. If I wanted to do that, I would have to prepare it in pure sine-wave state that extended to infinity in all directions, and it would therefore not be localized to Los Angeles or Chicago. The whole universe can only hold one such electron.

Comment: This sounds correct. Conversely if you knew two electrons were extremely close to each other, they must have very different momentum states, so I don't see that the PEP forbids this.

Comment: @RobJeffries: If you know that two electrons are both at a certain position, say $x=0$, then each electron's wavefunction is a Dirac delta function $\delta(x)$. This violates the Pauli exclusion principle, because they are both in the same state.

Comment: I'm sure you're right but now I'm getting a headache. If a particle is localised by a delta function at one instant, then in the next instant it can be anywhere in the universe. Perhaps I should ask another question for someone to clearly explain the last sentence of the quote. How close could they be?

Comment: @RobJeffries: *How close could they be?* The question assumes that the distance between them is known with infinite precision, which isn't normally the case.

Comment: As I understood it, you can get them as close as you like providing you give them sufficiently different momenta. Though I concede, not in *precisely* the same spot.